# javascript background image not changing

Tags: javascript, css

I need to change the background image of an img element, so I can show an sprite (a card sprite, in this case)

I have this code:

```
 document.getElementById("cardImg").style.background = "url(cards.jpg)" + (-349 / 13 * card) + "px " + (-36 * Math.floor(Math.random() * 4));
```

Where the `card` variable is a number that goes from 0 to 12
This is part of a bigger function, but when I execute that function the image does not change sometimes, and sometimes it does.

And I have thired to do things like changing `url(cards.jpg)` to `url(cards.jpg?v=Math.random())`but it does not change anything

Thanks for your help

Comment: look at the string you build.... `console.log("url(cards.jpg)" + (-349 / 13 * card) + "px " + (-36 * Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)))`

Comment: You have added "url(cards.jpg')" as a string and you are also saying card is a variable name, so you can not get the value of card if you add it as string.

Comment: Try something like this, 

document.getElementById("cardImg").style.background = "url(" + cards + ".jpg)" + (-349 / 13 * card) + "px " + (-36 * Math.floor(Math.random() * 4))

Comment: @epascarello what is wrong with it

Comment: Did you not look at it? It seems pretty obvious when you look at the string in the console.

Comment: @trupti im trying to get something like "url(cards.jpg) -27px -36px" so it works as a sprite

Comment: @epascarello i dont see anything wrong, and i looked at it several times

Comment: so you do not see anything wrong with `url(cards.jpg)-80.53846153846155px -72`, I am betting you did not look

Comment: @epascarello if you mean the decimals i've tried to round it and does not work anyway

Comment: How does it not match `url(cards.jpg) -27px -36px` What is different??

Comment: @epascarello woah the px at the end, now it works, thank you man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let card = 1;

console.log("url(cards.jpg)" + (-349 / 13 * card) + "px " + (-36 * Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)));
```

The error here is very obvious.

1. You should have a space seperating `...jpg) -26...` from `url(cards.jpg)-26.846153846153847px -36`.
2. You do not have a unit (e.g., `px`, `em`, etc) at the last number.

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle for reference.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/trupti11/0yofLkfu/) https://jsfiddle.net/trupti11/0yofLkfu/

JS

```
var cards = "https://i.imgur.com/kABxZg1";
var posX = 200;
var posY = 500;
document.getElementById("cardImg").style.background = "url(" + cards + ".jpg) "+posX+"px "+ posY+"px";
```